# Capistrano deploy to www folder

Tags: apache, deployment, capistrano

I have a webserver from an external host. The website is run from the /www folder. I configured and did a capistrano deploy to /www on the remote server. After playing with the settings, the deployment went as expected.

The problem is that now on my websserver I have the folders:

```
/www/current
/www/shared
/www/releases
```

but my webserver runs my wordpress site from /www not www/current. I cannot change this myself as I don't have the privileges to do so. What is the best way to solve this ?

@EDIT 
I created a command that rsyncs the current release to the www folder. This works, but is it the best option ?

```
namespace :emuse do
  desc "Copy files to www directory"
  task :copyfiles do
    run "rsync -azO /site/deployment/project/current/ /site/www"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Current path could be set like that:

```
set :current_path, "/www"
```

Comment: This does not work, because the www folder is generated by the hosting provider and therefore under sudo rights which I don't have.